# Reference a table in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with JPA and hibernate that I cannot figure out.
I got two seperate entities with data and I want to read/write data to table2 from table1.

**Table 1**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
@Data
public class Table1{

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "table2",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tableId", referencedColumnName =  "id"))
    private List<Table2> data = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Table 2**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
@Data
public class Table2{

    private String name;
    private String address;
}
```

So whenever I update table1 and it contains name and address I want to write it to table2, and when table one is fetched I want to serve all names and addresses in a list along with the object. How can I achieve this with JPA and Hibernate?

Comment: You have described your goal, but I don’t know what problem you’re encountering with achieving that goal.

Comment: What you ask can be done using Database triggers. Equivalent functionality in JPA is provided through "Entity Lifecycle Events" and "EntityListener"s. I would propose to stick to the DB trigger since the JPA events will not be triggered if the operation on the table is not through JPA i.e SQL query in CLI.

Comment: JPA is not for copying data from one table to another. One table represents one class, and the other table represents the other class. Create objects of the different types to put data in respective tables. Since you don't post what you are trying its pointless to guess

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to do is a one-to-many relation, not a many-to-many, as seen in your annotations. The many-to-many relation is when you use a third table to connect the two, that just has id-pairs for both tables.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
@Data
public class Table1{

    @OneToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    }, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Table2> data = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

You need to reference the Table1 object in Table2

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
@Data
public class Table2{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "table1_id")
    private Table1 owner;

    private String name;
    private String address;
}
```

I added that `orphanRemoval = true`, because without it people are often confused that they've removed something from the list, but it's still there the next time they fetch the data. It was something the JPA specifications missed until version 2.1.